# Cannot open a SQL server database

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server to connect to the database. But, I receive this error when I attempt to connect.

Code for connecting database

```
ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig();
Connection con = connectionConfig.CONN();
```

The error produces by Log

```
Cannot open database "FBMain" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Here is the code

```
public class ConnectionConfig {
    private String ip = "192.168.56.1";
    private String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private String db = "FBMain";
    private String un = "sa";
    private String password = "Password123";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL;
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I have checked the user mappings for user sa. The database role membership for FBMain is set to db_owner and public. But, I can't connect at all.

Comment: Is your database FBMain ONLINE?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't use internet and i only open sql server application with username sa.

Comment: What is the result of select state_desc
from sys.databases
where name = 'FBMain'?

Comment: the result is ONLINE

Comment: ONLINE is database status, it has nothing to do with internet. Database status maybe ONLINE, OFFLINE, RESTORING, SUSPECT, etc, you can only connect to database that is ONLINE, so what is the result of my query?

Comment: it is ONLINE. you can see that in my comment above.

Comment: Your error is strange because even when database requested by login is unaccessable, login that is sysadmin still connect to master. I have doubts on your SA login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159210/discussion-between-david-and-sepupic).

Comment: Please change your database to master, retry, and please exec as soon as you connected: select system_user, user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are TWO instances od SQL Server on `192.168.56.1`, `default` and named(`SQL`).

The app tried to connect to the default instance where there is no `FBMain` database.
This database exists on the named istance.

To connect to the `named instance` the connection string should specify the `port` (that can be found in `SQL Server error log` or in the `Configuration Manager`), or it can specify `instance name` like this: `192.168.56.1\SQL` or `ANIME-PC\SQL` and `SQL Server Browser` shuold run in the second case.

Comment: it works after some googling. i add port and change my ip to 10.0.3.2 because i use genymotion for testing my apps.